# extracting information from xml file in python

Tags: python, xml, nlp

I want to extract  information from a couple of xml file as here:
[image]

https://github.com/peldszus/arg-microtexts/blob/master/corpus/en/micro_b001.xml

I want to only extract this tag information:

```
<arggraph id="micro_b001" topic_id="waste_separation" stance="pro">
```

which is :
"micro_b001"
"waste_separation"

I want to save them as list

I have tried this:

```
myList = []  
myEdgesList=[]
#read the whole text from 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            with open(os.path.join(root, file), encoding="UTF-8") as content:
                tree = ET.parse(content)
                myList.append(tree)
```

this above code is correct it give information of each file as

```
<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree at 0x21c893e34c0>,
```

but this looks not correct

```
for k in myList:
    arg= [e.attrib['stance'] for e in k.findall('.//arggraph')  ]
    print(arg)
```

the second code doesn't give the required value to me

Comment: Have you tried the solutions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9797274/find-xml-element-based-on-its-attribute-and-change-its-value)?

Comment: it is kind of different. here i need information in first tag

Answer (score 0):

One way to handle this:

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse(myfile.xml)
for graph in tree.xpath('//arggraph'):
    print(graph.xpath('@id')[0])
    print(graph.xpath('@topic_id')[0])
```

Output:

```
micro_b001
waste_separation
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
import os
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils

path = 'test'
#read the whole text from 
myList = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xml'):
            myList.append(os.path.join(root, file))

for file in myList:
    xml = utils.getFileContent(file)
    doc = SimplifiedDoc(xml)
    arg = [(e['stance'],e['id'],e['topic_id']) for e in doc.selects('arggraph')]
    print (arg)
```

Result:

```
[('pro', 'micro_b001', 'waste_separation')]
```